# Hartl Ch 6 spec clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm working through the Michael Hartl book. I'm on section 6.3.3. I understand what we are trying to accomplish. However, to me, two of these specs seem to be testing the same thing:

From the user_spec.rb: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code-authenticate_spec

```
describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }          #1
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }   #2
    end
  end
```

Are specs 1 and 2 not both testing that the DB should not validate the user if his password is incorrect? How are these tests different?

Answer (score 0):

specs 1 and 2 are inverse of each other.

In the first one, you're passing the valid password to the authenticate method, which in this case returns the user object itself, then using 'should' to compare it to the subject user object

In the second, you're passing an invalid password to authenticate which then just returns false, which 'should_not' be equal to the subject user object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you misunderstood which two specs I'm referring to. I'm not talking about "with valid password". I'm talking about the two specs in "with invalid password" (see numbering).